# Access Azure KeyVault from Xamarin Form

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I need to get a secret from the keyVault (functionKey) so that I can access my functions.

I use the below code that works

```
    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var keyVaultClient =
        new KeyVaultClient(
            new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
    var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("mysecretIdentifier").ConfigureAwait(false);
    var key = secret.Value;
```

but the above requires in Visual Studio 2019 tool-options- Azure service Authentication I have to choose an account

How does it work once the app is deployed?
How does it know which subscription to use?

Just trying to figure out how it will authenticate the azure keyvault?
Any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your mobile application should never have to query directly the keyvault. Because if you do so your secrets could be retrieved (your secrets will be present in the memory of your mobile application). Check this [post](https://codemilltech.com/mobile-apps-azure-keyvault-dont-do-it/) about that.

I don't know what you are trying to do but best is to use Azure Functions Easy Auth. Basically it is you will request a token for your identified user on your xamarin application and use this token to query the Azure Function.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization

Comment: I totally agree but if you calling an azure function with AuthLevel=Function how do you do it? that post I read it so many times but it uses anonymous access and all the functions have to be set to "AuthLevel=Function. Where do you store the FunctionKey? Let me google Azure Function Easy Auth.Any good practical code snippet? I am trying to access all my functions that are not set to anonymous and not to store any secret in the mobile app

Comment: In the link I send you above (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) it is explained how to use Easy Auth, the page contains links to different how-to guides to configure authentication through different providers (depending on whether you choose to authenticate your user through Azure AD, Facebook, Google, Twitter ...). Once you have configured that you don't need anymore to use AuthLevel=Function, you just have to request a token and then to pass this token in your call to your azure function.

Comment: I have read the documentation and I think I need to use Azure Ad Login. My login has to be a "silent" login. I still have few gaps ,"url_scheme_of_your_app" is this the applicationName also wondering if there is an example out there that I can download /visualize. Sorry new to all this

Comment: I understand, don't worry authentication / authorization is not an easy topic for everyone. I am sorry but I won't be able to help you more as I never set up authentication in a Xamarin Forms application. Concerning your question about url_scheme, see [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34241) maybe. I think you can find some blogs where people have already done this kind of things.